# Error while uninstalling ADT version 21.0.1.201212060302

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, adt

I get the following error as shown below when I try to uninstall ADT version 21 because I need to update it to version 23(or whatver the latest version is)

ERROR:

```
An error occurred while uninstalling session context was: 
(profile=profile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Uninstall,  
operand=[R]org.eclipse.rcp.configuration_root.win32.win32.x86 1.0.0.I20120608-1200 --> 
null, action=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.touchpoint.natives.actions.CleanupzipAction).

Backup of file E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\eclipse.exe failed.
Can not remove : E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\eclipse\eclipse.exe
```

---

I also cannot setup the Android SDK in the preference section because Android SDK requires Android Developer Toolkit version 23.0.0 or above.  Current version is 21.0.1.2012-12-6-2-58.
So I need to update ADT but I get error as shown in the picture.
I tried running as Administrator while uninstalling, also tried disabling Antivirus software but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It happens due to the  name of .exe file of eclipse.

take a back up of eclipse.exe file and rename the existing eclipse.exe then copy the back up file again into the same folder of eclipse and open the old eclipse which is not renamed

after that ,
follow the same procedure to install the ADT

exit the window manually and again start it